# What is a word like "languor" for a more formal setting?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a noun that can be used like "languor", but is used in a mildly more formal setting? I believe languor is the stressless, lazy feeling one experiences while sunbathing at the beach or reclining on the porch. I would like a word that still denotes stresslessness/laziness, but perhaps while leaning back in a office chair or something.

E.g. Overcome by a feeling of _______, Fred neglected the urgent forms on his desk and instead opted to take a nap.

Comment: You could consider "lethargy" as an option. (Modify the sentence: "Overcome by lethargy, ...") it doesn't have the same flavour of pleasantness, though, which may or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: @L.Willmer, I was just about to write _lethargy_ too. You should add it as a detailed answer.

Comment: @alwayslearning Why shouldn't L. Willmer rather close-vote for lack of research? A quick look for synonyms of 'languor' turns up _lethargy, listlessness, weariness, lifelessness, lassitude, fatigue_ and others. And while I agree that 'lethargy' connotes sluggishness whereas 'languor' connotes sunbathing, a good answer would have to provide objective evidence that this is so.

Comment: Yes, I suggested to add it as a _detailed_ answer. Not in the current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accept that the person experiencing the languor is probably not very formal, but I don't think that takes away any formality from the word itself.

But if you just want to vary things up a bit, here's a word an online thesaurus suggested, which works pretty well:

*inertia* (google gave me "a tendency to do nothing or to remain unchanged")

> Overcome by *inertia*, Fred etc.